# Connect MySQL with Cloud Storage in GCP

Tags: mysql, storage, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am designing a network infrastructure, I am really new to this, I already have the initial part of the infrastructure defined, but now I find a detail, I need to design a scheme for data storage, where for example have:

• Instances with MySQL that only process the data but do not store anything, for example 2 GB of RAM and a 4-core processor.

• Another instance or service where I can store the data processed by MySQL, where the most important feature is the size of the HDD or SSD.
The data processed by MySQL must be stored in the other instance that I mention in the second point and also have to be able to access them in real time.

I was reading and I think the problem can be solved by connecting to MySQL & Cloud Storage, but I'm not sure if this is the solution. Currently there is a scheme similar to the following:

[Current Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kQYl.png)

I want to do the same scheme, but with google resources, I hope they can help me and sorry for me English

Comment: Cloud storage is not the same thing as block storage, which is what MySQL needs.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of Google Cloud Storage is to allow to store and retrieve any amount of data at any time, but you cannot modify data directly in Google Cloud Storage.

You can keep your scheme by using Google Compute VM instances and resizing or adding persistent disks when it requires more storage space [1].

However, if it is not required to keep your scheme, I recommend you to deploy your MySQL database in Google Cloud SQL that supports most common features of MySQL; the list of all differences between standard database and Cloud SQL functionality is provided here [2]. Cloud SQL offers high performance, scalability, and convenience. You can increase storage capacity and machine type of a Cloud SQL instance after its creation.

[1] Resizing a persistent disk: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd

[2] Differences between Cloud SQL and standard MySQL functionality: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#differences

Comment: More details about Google Cloud SQL for MySQL are available at this page [3] (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/)